# Backup strategy for Windows Server 2008 R2 and Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, hyper-v

I am in the process of planning a Hyper-V deployment with SCVMM 2008 R2. I have several VMs on VMWare Player (temporary solution) for stuff like Sharepoint 2007, 2010, and a couple of other server apps.

I want to develop a resilient backup plan for this. On the software side, Data Protection Manager 2010 will support all of the server apps I run (sQL Server 2008 R2, Sharepoint, Exchange, etc). But on the hardware side (storage), what is the best way to go? Drobo seems to have issues with Hyper-V juding by a few threads on here and doesn't support DPM 2010 (which is in beta anyway) but not even the 2007 version (see http://www.drobo.com/support/best_practices.php).

What storage device would work well? Do I need a home server or just an external usb drive? Capacity wise, 2tb will probably be best so I can have a small archive and implement a round-robin system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DPM 2007 doesn't support backing up to external/removable devices.

How many servers do you need to backup, it sounds like only a couple? Have you thought about using Windows Server Backup, instructions on how to register see this video - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd775213.aspx

Comment: There is actually a 3rd party product which allows backups to external devices.

Comment: Hi Blade, do you have any details on the 3rd party product that allows you to push DPM backups to external devices?

Comment: Also, you *can* connect to a Drobo, as long as it's over iSCSI. DPM doesn't allow backup to removable drives, but I've used DPM and a DroboPro before.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for larger shops, but for backups you might be okay. Buy smaller drives and more of them to get more speed out of it.